# Can I add a special character in the VSCode text editor gutter area in front of a line like the red spot of debug breakpoint did?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension. For a text editor, I need to put something in front of line of text, i.e. put a certain flag in the gutter area just like the red circle of debug breakpoint. Is there any API or event I can use? I don't need permanent storage for those flags' position, it's ok the flags refresh if the file is reopened.

I am thinking of leverage debugger adaptor, but that sounds stupid as I only need the red dot.